# Namespacing Rails models. How should this be done and what's the best syntax for calling the namespaced models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Let's assume we have a very large codebase and want to namespace a group of functionally-related code under a folder structure. Say we have a bunch of files related to Admin so we create an app/models/admin folder and place files like `admin.rb` and `admin_accounts.rb` under the models/admin folder.

Questions:
1. Do these classes now **need** to be wrapped in an admin module or does Rails do this for us automatically?
2. When creating a new admin, is there a way for us to not have to call it like `Admin::Admin.rb` or `Admin::AdminAccount.new`. The call sites range in the 100s. Do we have to change each call site to reference the wrapping module now? Or is there a way around this with the autoload feature?

In short, what's best practice? Do we now need to wrap the classes in a module? IF so, does that mean we now need to preface `Admin.new` and `AdminAccount` with the module? Is this necessary?